# $_ variable behaves differently when script is called from konsole and when called from another script

Tags: linux, csh

I am not much experienced with tch. To simplify the scenario, I created a script and just put "echo $_" there.

if I source the script like this:

> source set_env_vars.csh

I get "source set_env_vars.csh"

but if I run the script like:

> ./set_env_vars.csh

I get a different output 'some paths'

I want to understand what exactly $_ holds and why the outputs are different in two cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Environmental variables propagate from the shell to the sub-shell only.

`source set_env_vars.csh` adds the environmental variables to the shell.

`./set_env_vars.csh` adds the environmental variables to a sub-shell that exists only for the duration of this command. These changes are lost when the sub-shell exits and are not seen by the shell. This is why the outputs are different.